# Apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

This is the code I have:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <Segment ID="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </Segment>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="break">
  <Segment ID="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Segment>
  <Segment>#$NL</Segment>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to call the first template inside the second template so that I don't have to repeat the code? Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="break">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  <Segment>#$NL</Segment>
</xsl:template>
```

I use * here and it doesn't work. I tried @* and / but nothing works. The goal is for me to call it like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Name" mode="break"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `xsl:call-template` rather than `xsl:apply-templates`, you can set up a named template and then call it whenever you need it.

If I understand your question correctly, the repeated code is a Segment element with specified ID attribute and inner text string.  So you can give this template those two parameters, and specify them when you call it.  Like this:

```
<xsl:template name="segment">
   <xsl:param name="id"/>
   <xsl:param name="text"/>
   <Segment ID="{$id}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
   </Segment>    
</xsl:template>

...
   <xsl:call-template name="segment">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="name(.)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
   </xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the two templates you showed us with these two:

```
<xsl:template match="*" name="Segment">
  <Segment ID="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </Segment>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="break">
  <xsl:call-template name="Segment" />
  <Segment>#$NL</Segment>
</xsl:template>
```

I can see that in your original XSLT, the first template was concatenating a space onto the value, and the second wasn't. With the above approach, the space will be appended in both cases. Is that satisfactory for your requirements?

Comment: Wow, that works. Thanks. I thought if I use the name attribute I have to use the param. Guess I have to learn more about the call-template tag.

Comment: A template invoked with `call-template` will execute in the context of the current node, so this is a handy way to have more than one template share some common functionality.

Comment: You can also of course use modes, and do `<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="other"/>` to achieve the same effect.